# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NinjaWarzBot.py", line 354, in <module>
    stats = comm.init()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ninja warz bot\NinjaWarzLib.py", line 33,
 in init
    mf.seek(m.start()+len(cookieKey)) # reset file cursor
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
Press any key to continue . . .

def init():
    cookieDBFilename = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], "AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Cookies")
    cookieKey = "kongregate.ninjawarz.brokenbulbstudios.comPHPSESSID"
    f = open(cookieDBFilename, 'r+b')
    mf = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    mf.seek(0) # reset file cursor
    m = re.search(cookieKey+'\w+', mf)

    mf.seek(m.start()+len(cookieKey)) # reset file cursor
    global _sessionId
    _sessionId = mf.read(m.end() - m.start() -len(cookieKey))
    mf.close()
    f.close()

    return getMyStats()
```

That's my error and code. I'm confused as to why i'm getting this error. Can someone please help me? It's getting frustrating.

Comment: Provide clear information. When you are getting this error? What is the thing you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It seems `re.search(cookieKey+'\w+', mf)` returns `None`.

Comment: I get this error when I run the script.
@iMom0 how would I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to check that your regex actually matched anything. If it doesn't then the returned value from the appropriate methods will be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

you can print re.search(cookieKey+'\w+', mf) before you excute .start() ,so that you can see if you actually search something.
however,if you have couples strings match in you text, re.search only return one object